# Is it possible to get OpenSSL 3.1 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, openssl

I'm setting up Ubuntu servers and have been using version 22.04 LTS as the base image. We run security scans on all our servers and this version of Ubuntu raises safety violations for having OpenSSL 3.0.2 installed. According to apt I have the latest version of the openssl package.

Do I have to downgrade to 20.04 to avoid this issue, or can I upgrade OpenSSL on the servers themselves some other way, because apt ain't doing it.

Comment: [How can I tell if a CVE has been fixed in Ubuntu's repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/a/563416/158442) Don't just blindly trust some dumb security scanner. These crapbots just check plain version strings, they don't actually test for anything, and they don't even check package details.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you would install it manually with the source code.

Download the source code from [here](https://www.openssl.org/source/), selecting the version 3.1.

Extract files, go to the extracted files folder, and open the terminal there.

Then, build openssl with the classic commands:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

You can see some notes of building from the official openssl github repository [here.](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/NOTES-UNIX.md)

Comment: It is likely that `apt remove openssl` will want to remove a large number of other packages too (everything that depends on openssl, really). If so, **do not follow this advice** or you may end up with a crippled system.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, @telcoM you're absolutely right. So how could he manually install version 3.1 of OpenSSL? Would it be wrong to overwrite the binary provided by apt using 'make install'?

Comment: The classic `./configure` -> `make` -> `sudo make install` process will usually default to installing to the `/usr/local/` directory hierarchy instead of overwriting the version provided by package manager. Then, after a `sudo ldconfig` if necessary, if an application is programmed to accept "openSSL 3.0 or higher", it should automatically find the newer version in `/usr/local/lib/*` and use it, and any applications wanting "openSSL **3.0 only**" will still be satisfied by the version provided by the package manager.

Comment: However, it is important to understand that OpenSSL that has been patched by Ubuntu, e.g. version 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.10 **is not the same thing as unpatched Openssl 3.0.2 without any suffix** (see question comment by muru and [this question at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1438582/769591)). If your organization refuses to understand this, the way to fully replace OpenSSL 3.0.x with OpenSSL 3.1 might be to get an `apt`-packaged version of the OpenSSL source (e.g. from a newer Ubuntu release), and use `dpkg-buildpackage` to build a `*.deb` of it on Ubuntu 22.04, and install that with `apt`.